# Why does opening a file in Read block others from opening in Read+Write on a Windows Network Drive?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, network-shares, shared-folders

We have an Excel file that we use for data entry (located on a network drive).
We also have a python script on a server pulls data from the file.

Based on Computer Management, the file is opened on the server in Read Only. However, our user is not able to save the file while the script has the file open.

Why can't the user Read+Write while another user is Read Only? Is there a way to allow changes to a file while a user has it open in Read Only?

Comment: No, this cannot be achieved by modifying the file when it is opened as read-only. If it can be modified, then the security of the file is lost.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, when opening a file, the program specifies its access method,
such as read-only. It also specifies its share-mode, which is what others
are allowed to do with the file.

Evidently, your script does not allow the file to be modified while open.
This is only logical, as if file contents are read that do not correspond
to contents already in the memory cache, then bad things can happen.

If you are ready to take the risk of damaging the read-only session,
another user can use a program such as
[Unlocker](https://filehippo.com/download_unlocker/)
to unlock the locked file, on your own risk.

Comment: Good point about the risk, I think I'm going to keep the script as it is. It's an old version of python (Jython 2.5) with an old version of openpyxl (1.7.0). I'm able to force the file to close a little earlier using the `gc` module.

Answer (score 0):

There are far more properties for a program to access a file than read and write.

For instance, the first application to obtain access to the file can specify what "mode" it allows.

These are things like "share deny none" "share deny read" "share deny write" etc.. These flags control the access the SECOND+ entities are allowed to do with the file.

Your python script is opening the file using the wrong flags (as in Share deny write).

Fix your script and this problem might very well go away.. but then again.. your problem might get worse as having two different things writing to the same file us usually bad juju depending on circumstances.

I suggest trying it and seeing (after making a backup of the file of course).

Comment: @Troy - Concept of opening a file and prevent another users form modifying is pretty common across all operating systems.  Even operating systems like z/OS which is built around the concept of sharing files, does not allow a file to be edited and read, your use case is pretty non-standard.